# Java - summing up Array list values

Tags: java

I am building an array that ask how many different inputs you have, then allowing you to enter each input. At the end I want to sum them up, but I keep getting an error.
Also when I go above 5 inputs, I lose one..... For example when I respond to the first question: Enter "10". When I start adding different numbers in it stops at nine. Please help.

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses you have left: ");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    int[] numArr = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Enter the number of CUs for each course: ");
    for (int i=0; i<numArr.length; i++)
    {
        numArr[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    int totalSum = numArr + totalSum;
    System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is: " + totalSum);
```

Comment: Your logic for finding the sum does not make sense.

Comment: How can you do this `int totalSum = numArr + totalSum;`

Comment: `int totalSum = numArr + totalSum;` - what is it supposed to do? 1. `totalSum` is not defined yet. 2. You are adding `int` to an array of int's. This is obviously not working.

Comment: Lol `int totalSum = numArr + totalSum;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your logic and code to the following:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses you have left: ");
int size = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the number of CUs for each course: ");
int totalSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    totalSum+=input.nextInt();
}

System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is: " + totalSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses you have left: ");
int size = input.nextInt();

int totalSum = 0;
for (int i=0; i< size; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of CUs for each course: ");
    int cuNum = input.nextInt();
    totalSum += cuNum ;
}

System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is: " + totalSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your intended result is

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses you have left: ");
int size = input.nextInt();
int[] numArr = new int[size];
int totalSum = 0;
System.out.println("Enter the number of CUs for each course: ");
for (int i=0; i<numArr.length; i++)
{
    numArr[i] = input.nextInt();
    totalSum += numArr[i];
}

    System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is: " + totalSum);
}
```

Your other code didn't work mainly because of

```
int totalSum = numArr + totalSum;
```

You can't define totalSum to defines itself! And you can't just use numArr... numArr is an array - you have to access indexes, not the array as a whole!